# Server 2012 core (no GUI) Auto Logon

Tags: windows-server-2012, windows-server-core

I am trying to enable automatic logon in Windows Server 2012 Core (no GUI).  I followed the instructions that i have been following for years, detailed in [this Microsoft Support KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310584), but auto login is not working.

It works fine for Server 2012, with GUI, but not on Core.

For curious minds: I enable auto login it saves me time it's my lab, and isolated, so I don't have to worry about security.

Comment: Did it work for 2008R2 core?

Comment: i am not familiar with 2008R2 Core. i have only used 2008 R2 GUI

Answer (score 2):

You can always play with command line and add the following registry keys:

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\winlogon
```

Create following keys:

```
AutoAdminLogon = 1
DefaultUsername = currentUserName
DefaultPassword = currentPassword
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Autologon tool from Sysinternals http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963905 - or direct link: http://live.sysinternals.com/Autologon.exe

Tested on Hyper-V Server Core 2012 R2 (RTM)

Answer (score -1):

Open cmd or powershell and type: `control userpasswords2`

Select Administrator type password and that's it.

Comment: "Windows cannot find 'C:\Windows\system32\netplwiz.exe'. Make sure you types the name correctly, and then try again.

Comment: OP is asking about server core